# drupal8 displaying to_date based on from_date using java script - not showing up on the form

Tags: javascript, drupal-8

Iam new to drupal.. I have a form in drupal 7 which has to be moved to drupal8 . The form includes two date fields - a from date and a to date. The Dates are of type 'date_popup'.

I want to make the to_date automatically change to from_date . I have attached  js script and form module. The dates are not showing up on the screen. Is there something Iam missing.

```
PHP
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['suggested_date'] =
    array(
        '#type' => 'date_popup',
        '#title' => t('F Date:'),
      );

    $default_from = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')." +1 month"));
    $form['from_date'] = array(
    '#title' => t('from'),
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
    '#default_value' => $default_from,
    '#datepicker_options' => array('minDate' => 'today'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['to_date'] = array(
    '#title' => t('today'),
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
    '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($default_from." +1 day")),
    '#datepicker_options' => array('minDate' => date('d/m/Y', strtotime($default_from." +1 day"))),
    '#required' => TRUE,
   );    
    return $form;
  }
```

```
JS script

 (function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.testdate = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('#edit-from-date', context).change(function() {
        $('#edit-to-date', context).val($(this).val());
        var field_date1 =$('#edit-to-date', context).val($(this).val());
        console.log(field_date1);
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```
Module

function testdate_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
   $form['#attached']['library'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'testdate') . 'date_picker.js'; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define a library containing js file and attach it to the form:

**testdate.libraries.yml**

```yaml
date_picker:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    date_picker.js: {}
```

**YourForm.php**

```php
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Your current logic
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'testdate/date_picker';  // 'module_name/library_name'
  return $form;
}
```

And you should not use `hook_form_alter` without checking `form_id` because you will attach library to **all** forms. Instead you can attach the library directly in function `buildForm()` as above.

### Update:

Form element type `date_popup` does not exist in Drupal 8. please use `date` instead. You can check out supported types [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements/8.2.x)

Comment: ..I tried what you suggested, but I think Iam missing something else in my code ... when I go to the webpage  only the text "Select a range of days" shows up (I added this in the form ). The input for 'from' and 'to' date doesn't show up in the form.

Comment: @shalinicrescentia I just updated my answer. You should use `'#type' => 'date'` for the date elements.

Comment: @shalinicrescentia Pls check in the page source whether file `date_picker.js` has been loaded or not

Comment: @ KienNguyen - ... I tried with type=date ..... the feilds are displaying now but I think my js is the issue as I don't see any messages on the console log. when I look into the page source I see the following .        <br\> div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-date form-type-date js-form-item-from-date form-item-from-date"> <label for="edit-from-date">From Date:</label> <input type="date" data-drupal-selector="edit-from-date" data-drupal-date-format="Y-m-d" id="edit-from-date" name="from_date" value="" class="form-date" /> </div>` – shalini crescentia 3 mins ago